# How to get two different array objects together

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

Here i attached my json .

```
"mainSteps": [
  {
    "id": "9b3b64b4-d8a5-46d5-b464-066dc5c45dc3",
    "name": "Main Step 1",
    "steps": [
      {
        "name": "sub step 1.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "sub step 1.2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Main step 2"
    "steps": [
      {
        "name": "sub step 2.1"
      },
      {
      "name": "sub step 2.2"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "name": "Main Step 3",
    "steps": [
      {
        "name": "sub step 3.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "sub step 3.2"
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

am looking for the output like -->  [Main Step 1, sub step 1.1 , sub step 1.2] ,[Main Step 2, sub step 2.1 , sub step 2.2] , [Main Step 3, sub step 3.1 , sub step 3.2] . I spend the whole day for this output but am getting output like [[Main Step 1,Main Step 2,Main Step 3,sub step 1.1,sub step 1.2....]  Like that am getting different format's but am unable to get the actual output as i mentioned about , Can someone clarify me .

```js
 var dataProcess = {
            parentProcess:[],
            subProcess:[]
                             };                        
   var steps = mainData.steps; // Steps Having the Full json data                   
          var proc = [];
                 $scope.getSteps = function(steps) {
                    for (var i=0;i< steps.length;i++) {
                        dataProcess.parentProcess.push(steps[i].name);
                      for(var j=i;j<steps[i].steps.length;j++){
                    dataProcess.subProcess.push(steps[i].steps[j].name);
                    }
                   }
```

This is one of the way i tried ,

Comment: `mainSteps.map(x => [x.name, ...x.steps.map(y => y.name)])`? (not tested)

Comment: @gcampbell ,Underscore js right ? Nope dude... let me  check that...and update you.

Comment: It really Works :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need ES5 syntax:

```
var details = mainSteps.map(function(step) {
  return [ step.name ].concat((step.steps || []).map(function(substep){
    return substep.name;
  })
});
```

ES6 syntax:

```
var details = mainSteps.map(step =< [step.name].concat((step.steps || []).map(sub => sub.name));
```

If you need more recursion than one layer deep, you can use a function as the top level mapper, that calls itself.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do like this;

```js
var mainSteps = [
  {
    "id": "9b3b64b4-d8a5-46d5-b464-066dc5c45dc3",
    "name": "Main Step 1",
    "steps": [
      {
        "name": "sub step 1.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "sub step 1.2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Main step 2",
    "steps": [
      {
        "name": "sub step 2.1"
      },
      {
      "name": "sub step 2.2"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "name": "Main Step 3",
    "steps": [
      {
        "name": "sub step 3.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "sub step 3.2"
      }
    ],
  }
],
mapped = mainSteps.map(e => [e.name, e.steps[0].name, e.steps[1].name]);
console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using `Array.map` and `Array.concat` functions:

```
// supposing "obj" is your initial object
var dataProcess = obj.mainSteps.map(function (o) {
    return [o.name].concat(o.steps.map(function(v){ return v.name; }));
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(dataProcess, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
[
    [
        "Main Step 1",
        "sub step 1.1",
        "sub step 1.2"
    ],
    [
        "Main step 2",
        "sub step 2.1",
        "sub step 2.2"
    ],
    [
        "Main Step 3",
        "sub step 3.1",
        "sub step 3.2"
    ]
]
```

[DEMO link](https://jsfiddle.net/uxwv22ak/1/)

Comment: @Becky, see the DEMO link

Comment: got it, Thanks Buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

this way, it's working with various length of array and sub arrays :

```
var results = mainSteps.map(x => [x.name].concat(x.steps.map(y => y.name)));
```